# Why add a second resistor to a circuit in an Ohm's law practical?

Tags: resistance

Recently i have performed an experiment on Ohms Law. I tested different resistors in a simple circuit while measuring potential difference and current.

As my group was ahead of the class, the teacher came and added a second resistor in series to the resistor we were testing at the time and we redid all our measurements with this new circuit setup.

My question is, why did he do this and how does this increase accuracy of the results?

Comment: Why would you think it would increase the accuracy? As for why did he do it? Could be a number of things. Maybe he wanted you to learn about voltage dividers and calculate voltage drops over different resistors. Maybe it was just to change the value of resistance to make you calculate and verify a new current. Maybe you were too far ahead and he just needed to occupy you for a bit till others caught up and there wasn't much point to it.

Comment: Adding the resistor makes the circuit "different". A reasonable assumption is that the teacher thought that you may learn more with two groups of data to look at. With one resistor you can examine the ratio of V to I . With two resistors (the second made from two resistors) you have a second graph. You can expect that the 2nd will have a different slope to the first. What did you learn.

Comment: Why he did it - ask him.

Comment: I emailed him about it last week and this was his response: "If you understand why we did this, you can include it in the diagram and explain that. It’s a higher level of understanding, but not necessary. Alternatively just include the basic outline in your method and that is fine as well, ok?"

Comment: Well theres your answer. We dont know what diagrams you were doing, what your tasks were or anything so without being in your class and knowing your teacher, how are strangers on the internet supposed to read his mind?

Comment: When the second resistor was added, did you still measure the voltage across / current through the original resistor?

Comment: Huisman, yes we did, the measurements devices (multimeters) did not change location.

Answer (score 1):

If there were no other components such as a transistor or something like a Zener diode then the purpose was just to see the difference.

I suggest that you answer the following questions in your report.

- Did the voltage change? Why?
- Did the current change? Why?